# Printing a specific number of characters

Tags: python, string, function, printing, while-loop

I need help with printing a character (e.g. `"*"`) a certain number of times in a row. For example:

```
>>> printingAsteriks(4)
****
>>> printingAsteriks(6)
******
>>> printingAsteriks(0)

>>>
```

I have written:

```
def printAsteriks(ast):
    total="*"
    asteriks=1
    while asteriks<=ast:
        total=total+asteriks
        asteriks=asteriks+"*"
    print(ast)
```

and I know this is wrong but I don't really know where to go from here.

Comment: **Read the error messages carefully.** They will be telling you that you're trying to add the wrong kinds of things together. Then read your code (and write it out on paper, if necessary) and note what value is assigned to each name in each line (for example `total = total + asteriks` is `"*" = "*" + 1`, which is, I hope, obviously wrong). You may find e.g. http://pythontutor.com/ helpful if you cannot visualise this. Alternatively, note that e.g. `"*" * 4 == "****"`.

Answer (score 0):

`total=total+asteriks` This line is wrong. You are adding total which is the"*" to asterisk which is 1. You need to use the multiplication sign.

Just follow what Jonrsharpe told you in the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

as Jonrsharpe said your 'control' variable is not increased. It is because you have flipped lines 2 and 3, actually the correct version is to initialise total=1 and asteriks='*'.

Anyway, take into consideration that your are returning the input parameter and not the 'asteriks' string.